# Scroll synchronisation for multiple scrollable widgets

Tags: recursion, dart, flutter

Scroll synchronisation for multiple scrollable widgets:

I want to scroll second list if scroll first list and scroll first list if scroll second list.It is going to Recursive can anyone help for this, thanks in advance.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  ScrollController firstScroll = ScrollController();
  ScrollController secondScrollController = ScrollController();

  @override
  void initState() {
     super.initState();
     firstScroll.addListener(() {
    //THIS IS called when scroll is triggered,
        secondScrollController
           .jumpTo(firstScroll.offset); // THIS will sync the scroll;
     });

 secondScrollController.addListener(() {
    //THIS IS called when scroll is triggered,
        firstScroll
           .jumpTo(secondScrollController.offset); // THIS will sync the scroll;
     });
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            SingleChildScrollView(
             // this is the first scroll
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                controller: firstScroll, // THIS IS THE FIRST SCROLL CONTROLLER
                child: Container(
                   //TODO: add your content here here
                ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
               scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
               controller: secondScrollController,
               // HERE YOU SET THE SECOND CONTROLLER
               child: Container(
                  //TODO: add your content here
               ),
             )
        ],
    ),
 );
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because every time you call `jumpTo` method it call the first one, and the first one call the second one and you will have an infinity loop.

The solution is that you create your own ScrollController with it owns method to jump to another position without notification.

This is the custom scroll controller that you can create:

```
            class CustomScrollController extends ScrollController {
              CustomScrollController({
                double initialScrollOffset = 0.0,
                keepScrollOffset = true,
                debugLabel,
              }) : super(
                        initialScrollOffset: initialScrollOffset,
                        keepScrollOffset: keepScrollOffset,
                        debugLabel: debugLabel);

              @override
              _UnboundedScrollPosition createScrollPosition(
                ScrollPhysics physics,
                ScrollContext context,
                ScrollPosition oldPosition,
              ) {
                return _UnboundedScrollPosition(
                  physics: physics,
                  context: context,
                  oldPosition: oldPosition,
                  initialPixels: initialScrollOffset,
                );
              }

              void jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(double value) {
                assert(positions.isNotEmpty, 'ScrollController not attached.');
                for (_UnboundedScrollPosition position
                    in new List<ScrollPosition>.from(positions))
                  position.jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(value);
              }
            }

            class _UnboundedScrollPosition extends ScrollPositionWithSingleContext {
              _UnboundedScrollPosition({
                ScrollPhysics physics,
                ScrollContext context,
                ScrollPosition oldPosition,
                double initialPixels,
              }) : super(
                      physics: physics,
                      context: context,
                      oldPosition: oldPosition,
                      initialPixels: initialPixels,
                    );

              /// There is a feedback-loop between aboveController and belowController. When one of them is
              /// being used, it controls the other. However if they get out of sync, for timing reasons,
              /// the controlled one with try to control the other, and the jump will stop the real controller.
              /// For this reason, we can't let one stop the other (idle and ballistics) in this situation.
              void jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic(double value) {
                if (pixels != value) {
                  forcePixels(value);
                }
              }
            }
```

And just call to `jumpToWithoutGoingIdleAndKeepingBallistic` instead of `jumpTo` .

A working sample here:

https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/75e55ca2e4cee03bff41a26254d6fcf6

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but If I tried like this the bouncing effect is missing and the list goes even for empty space.(i.e.., more than the extent) added image in Question.

Comment: shrinkWrap: true  , remove the bouncing effect of your List, if you remove that value you could have some issues in your layout, try using Slivers

Comment: It is an single child scroll controller, and we want bouncing effect as per the requirement

Comment: sorry, I updated my code: check again -> https://gist.github.com/diegoveloper/75e55ca2e4cee03bff41a26254d6fcf6

Comment: Not working dude. bouncing effect is not coming and scroll is not free. it is Jerking.

Comment: Did you run my sample? I modified the scroll controller code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191932/discussion-between-siva-kumar-and-diegoveloper).